# Write to file with C++ dup2

Tags: c++, dup2

Alright I am trying to read from one file and write to another.

I have other things to add such as grabbing info from the first file but for testing I am trying to get it to write to the second file.

My understanding was that everything after the dp2() call would output to the second param. Right?

```
    using namespace std;
    using std::string;
    using std::ostream;
    using std::endl;
    string str;



    int main(){


    int file= open("./input.txt", O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_APPEND, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
        if(file==-1){
            cout<<"Error: "<<errno<<endl;
        }
    int file2= open("./output.txt", O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_APPEND, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
        if(file2==-1){
            cout<<"Error: "<<errno<<endl;
        }

    int retval = dup2(file,file2);
        if(retval == -1){
        cout<<"Error: "<<errno;
        }

    printf("yeah");


    close(file);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I'm not sure what led you to believe that you need to use `dup2()`. Don't use it here, it's not needed and will do the wrong thing.

Second, to write output to a low-level file descriptor, use `write()`:

```
write(file2, "yeah\n", 5);
```

Don't forget to `close(file2)` when you're done with it.

Comment: mm well that was easy, my teacher was actually the one to tell us to use it

Comment: Well, if you *want* to use `printf`, then you can actually `dup2(file, 1)` which makes file descriptor 1 (stdout) write to your newly opened file. But doing so is a bit tricky and unusual, because once you do that you can't write to the original stdout anymore (unless you also save it somewhere else). I'd stick with `write()` for a simple program.